# Why is $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] not evaluating to the expected value?

Tags: php

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin, and I'm having some issues with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

This is pointing to something that's completely incorrect.  I'm calling this from my plugin directory within my Wordpress installation, and it comes up with `http://www.richmindonline.com/testenvironment/wp-admin/www.richmindonline.com`

The correct path for this I'm guessing should be simply `http://www.richmindonline.com/testenvironment`. Is it possible to trim this down or somehow create a re-direct within my plugin file?

I'm thinking I don't need to post code for this.  Please let me know if you would like me to post a portion of the code.

***UPDATE***

Here's my .htaccess file in the root directory of that installation if that would help.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testenvironment/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /testenvironment/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: How do you use that variable?

Comment: A host never has a directory in it. You should really be seeing `www.richmindonline.com`. And, yes, you definitely need to post _a testcase_.

Comment: Wonder if there are some .htaccess files messing with the value.

Comment: The description of `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` includes [_Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one._](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) -- in other words, whatever the _client_ supplied for the `Host:` HTTP header. What are your clients supplying?

Comment: I'm using it in a form.  `action=<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]."process.php;?>`

Comment: I wouldn't mind someone taking a look if they want in my Wordpress backend.  The plugin is actually up and running, just resolving to the wrong form action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to point to a file in your plugins directory, one of ways I regularly do it is to use the plugins_url function, where in the following example 'yourfile.php' would be replaced with your unique value, in this case 'process.php':

```
$new_variable = plugins_url( 'yourfile.php', _FILE_ );
```

This would set the variable (for most Wordpress installs) to 'http://YOURDOMAIN.com/wp-content/plugins/yourfile.php'. However, the good thing about using the plugins_url function is that if someone has a non-standard Wordpress install and the plugins are located in a different folder, the function can still figure out where the correct PHP file is.

If the PHP file you want to locate is in a subfolder, just amend 'yourfile.php' to 'subfolder/yourfile.php'.

If I misunderstand what you're trying to accomplish, and you just want the base url, Wordpress can use the home_url() function. See (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url).

Another way to get to a file in a plugin folder is to use plugin_dir_url().

Example:

```
$new_variable = plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'yourfile.php';
```

Then in the form, use:

```
<action = "<?php echo $new_variable; ?>">
```

All of the various url functions are outlined here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url.

Comment: Chris, I think I'm only able to use home_url in the template files.  Am I incorrect on that?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to call up the baseurl of the installation, and it needs to be a dynamic call, since the users directory will always be different

Comment: Chris, that is doing it!!!  Let me test on another installation and I'll go ahead and vote your answer.  My bad for assuming home_url() was only good for template files.

Comment: The home_url() function works in the plugins file. I've used it here and there with my own WP development. Also, you can use site_url(). The difference is that site_url points to the folder of the installation, so if you're using a subdirectory for your main install, it would be set to 'http://base_url/sub_directory'. The difference is outlined in a book I can't recommend highly enough for WP plugin development called Professional Wordpress Plugin Development by Brad Williams.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I remember, the `HTTP_HOST` is provided by the client.

You could always trim it with a function or use $SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and some other tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
```

Comment: Correction, that actually makes it even worse.  Here's what I show when I replace it with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.  I get `http://www.richmindonline.com/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline`

Comment: The code is placed inside of a file called mwfinder.php, which is the primary file for my plugin.  The file is located within `http://www.richmindonline.com/testenvironment/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/mwfinder.php`

Comment: would you like to look for yourself?  I can chat if needed. I'm just sick of this issue.  It's the last thing I need to get off my plate.

Comment: Try this $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

Comment: The suggestions seem to make sense, but all suggestions are just adding on to the tail of the incorrect path.

Comment: no......it brings up the root directory, but like the other commands, it still is calling up the wp-admin directory.  I just posted my .htaccess file if you want to look.